# youtube-dl do not working.HTTP error 429: too many requests How can i solve this problem? youtube-dl is up-to date

Tags: youtube-dl

```
[youtube] lMttqRuFmL8: Downloading webpage
ERROR: Unable to download webpage: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests (caused by HTTPError()); please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; type  youtube-dl -U  to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
```

Comment: What OS/release are you using?   (that is a 'universe' or community package, so is no longer supported for 16.04 LTS for example, so issues with 16.04 should be expected).

Comment: ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: @TonmoyAhmed Latest version should report: `2020.03.24`. If this is ok try altering your command line to: `youtube-dl -4 URL`

Answer (score 12):

Using `--cookies` works for me.

Install the `cookies.txt` addon on Firefox. Export cookie.

```
$ youtube-dl --cookies cookies.txt www.youtube.com/watch?v=..
```

Comment: Amazing! Chrome/Opera users can get [the "Get cookies.txt" extension on the Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/get-cookiestxt/bgaddhkoddajcdgocldbbfleckgcbcid?hl=en).

Answer (score 9):

In this issue, @dstftw explains that all IPv6 addresses get banned by YouTube.

https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/21729

So, `--force-ipv4` should help. If it doesn't, the another workaround could be attaching a cookie from your browser with `--cookies` option.

Comment: `--force-ipv4` works for me, thank you

Comment: I solve it by using  `--force-ipv6`

Answer (score 3):

**Perhaps you are actually sending too many request** at the given time.

The status code 429 refers to TooManyRequest. In the real scenario you are sending more than expected requests on that site.

You could try later or change your IP using a proxy or VPN.

Comment: What worked for me was to *disconnect* the VPN and to add `--force-ipv4` to the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating youtube-dl to the latest version.

```
youtube-dl -U
```

if installed via PIP

```
pip install --upgrade youtube-dl
```

Answer (score 1):

this is mentioned in the [FAQ](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#http-error-429-too-many-requests-or-402-payment-required) official docs in detailed explanation

just [pass cookies](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#how-do-i-pass-cookies-to-youtube-dl),

the command line should be something similar to this

```
youtube-dl -F --cookies=cookies.txt VIDEOURL
```

this solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a new way to solve this. I don't know if it is also useful for you.
Video url is like `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoAddress&list=listAddress`
Change the url to `www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoaddress`

The whole command is
`youtube-dl --proxy 127.0.0.1:1080 "www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoAddress" --force-ipv4  --no-check-certificate`